# How to know which part of a customised cell have been clicked on in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

[image]I am doing a project via swift . I've defined a collection view and customised its cell such that it would look like the image down . Now , once I click on the cell , my function will tell me that I have clicked on which cell but I want to get more detailed info for example I get the picture in cell number 2 . For that purpose I tried to define a tap gesture but it seems that it doesnt work ? here is all my code :

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

```
class ViewUSRController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource  {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var cell : MyCollectionViewCell?

    var names = ["Danial" , "dkfloza" , "Kosarifar" , "IOS" , "Learning", "sina" ]
    var likes = ["23" , "7" , "17" , "100K" , "1000K" , "100"]

    var dislikes = ["0","0","0","0","0","0"]





    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerView = AVPlayer()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .black
        self.collectionView.delegate = self




        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.cell?.myLabel, action:#selector(handleTap))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired =  1
        cell?.myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return self.names.count
    }


    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
         cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell?.myLabel?.text = self.names[indexPath.row]
        cell?.myLabel?.textColor = .black
        cell?.likes_num?.text = likes[indexPath.row]
        cell?.dislike_num?.text = dislikes[indexPath.row]
        cell?.likes_num?.textColor = .black
        cell?.dislike_num?.textColor = .black


        return cell!

    }






//    
//    
//    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        // handle tap events
//        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
//        
//        
//        
//        
//    }


    func handleTap(){
        print("hello")
    }







}






class MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell{
    //appClub
    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
    //imagePlace
    @IBOutlet var viewTesting: UIView!
    //likes
    @IBOutlet var likes_num: UILabel!
    //dislikes
    @IBOutlet var dislike_num: UILabel!











}
```

Comment: you could just put buttons on the labels and autolayout them as center+equal widths + equal heights, then create delegate or closure based actions;

Comment: There are too many best practices for this. But in each practice you have to handle `UITouch` objects your own. Try using `touches` events and collection view delegate together. Identify your item (cell) which is being touched and location of touch in collection view (or cell upto you). Later then you can map that touch location in touched item's coordinate system to get the view.

Comment: One more thing if you try to use any gesture to achieve your job , you might alter responder (`UIResponder` objects) hierarchy. This will make things worse for you.

Answer (score 2):

-> Add gesture to table view

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        tap.delegate = self
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

-> Detect tap

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let tableView = gestureRecognizer.view as! UITableView
    let point: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: tableView)
    if (tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) != nil) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

-> find the location in cell and by giving tag to the subview view(eg. imageView, label) you can get the exact view as well.

```
public func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerState.ended == tap.state) {
        let tableView = tap.view as! UITableView
        let point: CGPoint = tap.location(in: tableView)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath!, animated: false)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath!)
        let pointInCell = tap.location(in: cell)
        if ((cell?.imageView?.frame)!.contains(pointInCell)) {
            // user tapped image
        } else {
            // user tapped cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to convert the code u've given from tableView to CollectionView . It's all good except the line `if ((cell?.imageView?.frame)!.contains(pointInCell)) ` it seems that after `cell?` I cant take any of the elements I have in my cell such as labels or imageView or ....
BTW for tap detection the selector should be `#selector(self.handleTap(tap:))` otherwise it will give compilation error as for ambiguous usage :)

Comment: Okay, so whats is the problem now that you are not able to access label cell?.myLabel?         You can access those properties if those are defined public or internal in cell class.